# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException in a @WebMvcTest test class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I would like to test my rest endpoint in `BookRestController`. I write one test with `@WebMvcTest`.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(BookRestController.class)
public class BookRestControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private CategoryService categoryService;

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Test
    public void should_create_new_category_when_try_to_update() throws Exception {

        given(categoryService.getCategoryById(20L)).willReturn(null);
        Category category = new Category("Fantastyka");

        ResultActions resultActions = mockMvc.perform(put("/api/category/10")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(category)));

        resultActions.andExpect(status().isNoContent());

    }
}
```

In the repository package I have 4 repositories but in my testing endpoint I use only one of them.
[image]

And this is my method from `BookRestController`

```
@RestController
public class BookRestController {

    @Autowired
    private CategoryService categoryService;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/api/category/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<Category> updateCategory(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Category category){

        return ResponseEntity
                .status(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
                .body(categoryService.updateCategory(id, category));
    }
}
```

Now when I run test I gets an error

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'demoApplication': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'com.sda.spring.demo.repository.BookRepository' available: expected at
>   least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency
>   annotations: {}

Why? I don't use `BookRepository` in my test. How can I fix this?

Full Log:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
>
> at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.postProcessFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:99)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.injectFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:79)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:54)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
>     at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)   at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
>   Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'demoApplication': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'com.sda.spring.demo.repository.BookRepository' available: expected at
>   least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency
>   annotations: {}   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:767)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:127)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
>     ... 25 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'com.sda.spring.demo.repository.BookRepository' available: expected at
>   least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency
>   annotations: {}   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1646)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1205)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:855)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:758)
>     ... 43 more

Spring Boot: v2.1.0.RELEASE

EDIT:
It works. I miss about `@Autowire` `BookRepository` in my `DemoApplication`...
I deleted this code and now it works

```
@Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private BookRepository bookRepository;

    private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    @Autowired
    public DemoApplication(BookRepository bookRepository, CategoryRepository categoryRepository) {
        this.bookRepository = bookRepository;
        this.categoryRepository = categoryRepository;
    }
```

Comment: And what does your bean demoApplication look like ? Because it needs your Repo

Comment: @Sodala you're right I miss about `@Autowired` in my `DemoApplication`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your main application class will load any bean defined, or functionality that enables via annotations.

e.g. `@EnableSchedling`, `@ComponentScan`, `@Import` etc.

Will all load up in a slice test.

See this documentation for more detail,

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-user-configuration

> If you structure your code in a sensible way, your @SpringBootApplication class is used by default as the configuration of your tests.
>
> It then becomes important not to litter the application’s main class with configuration settings that are specific to a particular area of its functionality.

Answer (score 2):

I want to add something to the question. Your CategoryService is depending on BookRepository. So in your test case, you have to mock it too. Because it is a WebMvcTest, not a SpringBootTest. So you can also try adding:

```
@MockBean BookRepository bookRepository
```

In your **BookRestControllerTest** class.